# Function that loops through an array and filters out a specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a json and based on the json i have to create a table.

Each "row" is an actual row in the table and every "sub_row" is an indicator that there is a collapsible row under the main one and so on.

Each row has a delete function and the row is give as a parameter plus the main array.

I need a function that iterates through all the objects and all the nested objects to match the specific row and filter it out.

```
{
   "row":{
      "property1":"1",
      "property2":"2"
   },
   "sub_row":{
      "first_extra":{
         "records":[
            {
               "row":{
                  "property1":"1",
                  "property2":"2",
                  "property3":"3"
               },
               "sub_row":{
                  "second_extra":{
                     "records":[
                        {
                           "row":{
                              "property1":"1",
                              "property2":"2",
                              "property3":"3"
                           },
                           "sub_row":{
                              
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "row":{
                              "property1":"2470",
                              "property2":"1043",
                              "property3":"546 765-7237"
                           },
                           "sub_row":{
                              
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

For example i want to delete this part:

```
"row":{
                                  "property1":"2470",
                                  "property2":"1043",
                                  "property3":"546 765-7237"
                               },
```

Tried multiple function but none seem to work

Comment: *"I have a json"*: that is a JavaScript object, and it is not (valid) JSON.

Comment: *"Tried multiple function"*: please show your attempt and explain what the problem is with it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you asked, remove object that matches nested object's value.

```
function filterTree(data, row2delete) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (key === "row") {
      if (!isSameRow(row2delete, value)) {
        acc[key] = value;
      }
    }
    
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      const subValues = value.map(el => filterTree(el ,row2delete));
      acc[key] = subValues;
    }
    
    if (key === "sub_row" || key.endsWith("_extra")) {
      acc[key] = filterTree(value, row2delete);
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function isSameRow(obj1, obj2) {
  for (const key in obj1) {
    const value = obj1[key];
    if (key && obj2[key] && obj2[key] === value) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(filterTree(data, {"property1":"1","property2":"2","property3":"3"}))
```

If your input type is an array then you can wrap it with map:

```
function filter(values, row2delete) {
  return values.map(item => filterTree(item, row2delete));
}

console.log(filter(data, {"property1":"1","property2":"2","property3":"3"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, If you have a raw data then move it to the `data.json` file.

```
    let data;
    // get the data from the file
    fetch("data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        // set the filtered data to the data.
        data = filterRowById(result, "row");
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    
    function filterRowById(jsonData, rowId) {
      const filteredData = { ...jsonData };
    
      // delete the data you want to delete with delete method
      delete filteredData[rowId];
    
      return filteredData;
    }
```

check the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-mirzakhani-cvj6hg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark